# How to show unsorted images in mvc5 with Razor engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, for-loop, razor, responsive-design

I'm using `mvc5` with `razor view engine` and I have a table of images in my DB , I want show 3 images in first line, then show some text in the next line, and then  show 2 images in the next line with some text which will repeat by `for loop` like this image

[image]

my current code is :

```
 <div style="padding: 0;">
    @foreach (var item in Model.MainGoods)
    {
        <div  class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img  src="@Url.Content(item.GoodImage.ToString())" />
            </a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Can anyone help me do it?

Comment: You must handle it using HTML/CSS :)

Comment: thanks :) , but I don't know how handle it , cause my images called from DB with `For` @SirwanAfifi

Comment: it's true define a counter variable  to  save number of images showed then applyed css ?!

Comment: @shimaamini did you try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<div style="padding: 0;">
    @{
        var count =1;
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model.MainGoods)
            {
                if (count <= 3)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-4 well">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="@Url.Content(item.GoodImage.ToString())"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    if (count == 3)
                    {
                        //new row
                        @Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"row\">")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="col-md-6 well">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="#"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    if (count == 5)
                    {
                        //new row
                        @Html.Raw("</div><div class=\"row\">")
                    }
                }
                if (count < 5)
                {
                    //increment the count
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //reset the count
                    count = 1;
                }

            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```